# Syntax highlighting blocks of code with LaTeX and literate programming tools

Tags: highlighting, minted, sourcecode, literate-programming

Using packages like [`minted`](http://ctan.tug.org/pkg/minted) (thanks to [Pygments](http://pygments.org/)), LaTeX can generate beautifully highlighted/colored source code. Literate programming tools such as [`noweb`](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/) and [`cweb`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CWEB) can generate beautifully typeset and readable documentation.

Ideally, I would like that the docs generated by `noweb` and `cweb` have high quality syntax coloring, and this seems like a problem that someone on either community may have tackled. So here is the question:

Does anyone know how to get `noweb` and related tools to use `minted` or a similar LaTeX package for syntax coloring?

Comment: I have written `pygnoweb`, a `noweb` filter that uses Pygments to typeset the blocks of source code with LaTeX. It is available at https://bitbucket.org/romildo/pygnoweb.